# QCheckBox->isChecked() issue

Tags: c++, qt, qcheckbox

The following code is not working when the checkbox is checked. Whether the checkbox is checked or not, it jumps to the "else" statement.

```
   void MainWindow::runButtonClicked()

        {
            if (MainWindow::betAllRed->isChecked()==true){
                red.didBet=true;
                qDebug()<<"bet Red true";
            } else{
                qDebug()<<"red not checked";
            }
        }
```

is there anything noticeably wrong here or is the issue elsewhere? 
Do I need to connect a slot to get the check state?

Comment: What _looks_ wrong is the way you access the `betAllRed` member. Using simply `betAllRed->` (without qualifier) or `this->betAllRed` if you need disambiguation would be more usual.

Comment: @Mat it's not wrong, it's just redundant. That syntax can be used to access an identifier in a specific namespace/scope, MainWindow:: in this case, which would be used anyway. (Edit: But I guess you know this, now that I re-read what you wrote in your comment, but leaving this as clarification anyway.)

Comment: Did you use Designer to create the GUI?

Answer (score 1):

the problem is the way you access the betAllRed checkbox.
if you are using the designer you can access it using Ui;

```
if(ui->betAllRed->isChecked())
```

if you are using your own code:

```
QComboBox *betAllRed = new QComboBox(this);
```

just access it using:

```
if(this->betAllRed->isChecked())
```

Answer (score 1):

What I suspect you are doing wrong is, you actually have two `betAllRed` fields: You have created and initialized `QCheckBox* MainWindow::betAllRed`, and then you also have a checkbox in MainWindow::ui (possibly with same name, if you renamed it in Designer, otherwise with the default name created by Designer).

If this is the case, remove your own `betAllRed`, then fix the code to use `ui->betAllRed` to access the checkbox (and possibly rename the checkbox in Designer if it has default name now).

And then a coding style note about this line of yours:

```
if (MainWindow::betAllRed->isChecked()==true){
```

That line is equal to just this, which would be much shorter and clearer:

```
if (betAllRed->isChecked()) {
```